# Error giving confirm button a class Producing error

Tags: css, forms, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I ran across an error with the Form helper. I tried adding a class to a `Form->postLink`. Like so:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink(
    'Delete',
    array('action' => 'delete', $location['Location']['id']),
    array('class' => 'btn btn-small btn-primary'),
    array('confirm' => 'Are you sure?'));
?>
```

I also tried adding the class array after the confirm array, and before the action array; but to no avail. This is the error I get:

> Notice (8): Array to string conversion [CORE/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php, line 1786]

That line reads:

```
$options['onclick'] ="if(confirm('{$confirmMessage}')) { {$onClick} }";
```

So when I put the class array after the action it lets the class be applied to the button but throws the above error. If I put it before the action the class is not applied and I still get the error. I don't know what the problem is but I have scoured the internet (and docs) for an answer but have found nothing even close...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink(
                'Delete',
                array('action' => 'delete', $location['Location']['id']),
                array('class' => 'btn btn-small btn-primary'),
                'Are you sure?');
?>
```

Reading [the docs](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-FormHelper.html#_postLink), the fourth parameter is a string, not an array.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this would help, im not sure where you get $confirmMessage
Form->postLink( 'Delete', 'action' => 'delete', $location['Location']['id'], 'class' => 'btn btn-small btn-primary', 'confirm' => 'Are you sure?'); ?>

Comment: I use that line in the view to produce the link. This is CakePHP 2.xx. The link will still work and the class even gets applied but there is still an error message(The one from above). In cake you must make separate arrays for each accepted param. The $this->Form->postLink() function accepts 4 params: TITLE, URL, OPTIONS(This is where all html attributes go), and CONFIRM(Specifically for making confirm popouts.)

Comment: Here is the link to the cphp bin so you can see MY code.    http://bin.cakephp.org/pastes/nick/dc50m